# Need help with the sentence structure for my pitch, thanks!

Tags: phrase-requests, terminology, speech, syntactic-analysis

Back story: I am to give a 3 minute pitch on a task i worked on.

I would like to something like,
"**As a general knowledge, we know that smartphones are dominated by IOS and android. Which is why working on these operating systems are important**"

*Something like that...* But i don't know if i have to give like a solid quote from a credible source or i can just throw the word "allegedly" in there.

Please help me with constructing this sentence!

Thanks and with Love,
English newbie <3

Comment: You don't need "allegedly" if you can find a source that shows the current market share for these two operating systems (which is an easy Google search). Then you can replace "As a general knowledge," with "From market research, we know..."

Comment: It doesn't appear to be a question about the English language or its usage.

Answer (score 1):

I would also make two small edits: "Recent studies (or quote a specific study) show that **the smartphone market** is dominated by IOS and android. **This** is why working on these operating systems **is** important."

The verb (is) needs to agree with the subject (working). "Working (...) **is** important", not "These operating systems are important."